# Amazon S3 life cycle rule for sub folder contents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

With this reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496566/amazon-s3-life-cycle-rule-for-folder)

My s3 bucket name say testbucket.

If I create prefix for a rule say.

subfolder1/

All the objects in it are applied this rule.

But it is not getting applied for objects inside subfolders.

subfolder1/subfolder2/item1
subfolder1/subfolder3/item3

How to create a common prefix for a folder so that all the sub folder contents of the folder also gets this rule.